# Sticky Navbar doesn't work in bootstrap-vue when using in a component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vuejs2, navbar, sticky, bootstrap-vue

I'm working with bootstrap-vue and as you can see in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/behzadim/7pxtubcd/9/), sticky property is working correctly when used in navbar.

The problem is when I move this navbar to a separate **component** and call it, sticky attribute fails to work correctly.

```html
<b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="dark" variant="info" sticky>
   <b-navbar-brand href="#">NavBar</b-navbar-brand>      
</b-navbar>
```

**fixed="top"** is still working when using as a **component**.

```html
<b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="dark" variant="info" fixed="top">
   <b-navbar-brand href="#">NavBar</b-navbar-brand>      
</b-navbar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS `position: sticky` is not supported by all web browsers.  Using the latest Chrome, your fiddle is working for me though.

Answer (score 4):

I just encountered the same problem. It wasn't due to browser incompatibility stuff though. My navbar was wrapped in another logical component and sticky didn't work there.

Adding the following css to the wrapping component did the trick:

```
.wrapper {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

You might want to checkup on how to get the css to to work on other browsers than chrome.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="fixed-top"><b-navbar></b-navbar></div>
```

you can use class fixed-top that exist already in bootstrap.css